# Grails .save() is not saving an associated Domain

Tags: grails

I have a domain **Guest**  which has a **belongsTo** association with **Person** and  **User** domains as follows :

```
class Guest {

    static belongsTo = [
            person:Person,
            user : User // owner for guest
    ]


}
```

In my service **GuestService.groovy** , i am trying to update associated **Person** info associated with a given **guest** :

```
@Transactional
    def updateGuests(def guestArray) {

        guestArray.each { data ->

            User user = User.findById(data["userId"])
            Guest guest = Guest.findByIdAndUser(data["guestId"] , user)
            if( ! guest )
                throw new NotFoundException("Invalid input parameters")

            println(" email : " + guest.person.email + " new email " + data["email"])

            Person person = guest.person
            //person = Person.findById(person.id)

            person.email = data["email"]
            person.phoneNumber = data["phoneNumber"]

            person.save(flush:true)
            //guest.save(flush: true)
        }
    }
```

I am unable to update Person info and i don't receive any errors too.
I Debugged the code and all the values are present till exit of the debug point .I searched on internet and other related questions on this stack but no question is related to this kind of problem .

Comment: You probably have a validation error: http://docs.grails.org/3.1.6/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html

Comment: related: [Why is GORM not saving my object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9177563/217324)

Comment: i am new to grails, studying basics from these pages will surely help me ,Thanks for links

Comment: didn't check the links, but `save(flush: true, failOnError: true)` will show you the error. You can work your way up from that. And also - `findById()` is the same as `get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `person.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`?

It should overwrite a default behavior of returning `null` on save error and return exception instead.